# bash script to check zabbix java gateway

Tags: centos6, zabbix

I wrote simple script to check status of a service and when service is down search live processes for the service and kill them, then remove pid file and restart service.

The problem is that the script is not always able to remove the pid file which results in that the script is not able to restart the service.

This is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin
echo $(date +%d/%m/%Y-%H:%M)
service zabbix-java-gateway restart
sleep 1
service zabbix-java-gateway status > /tmp/status_zabbix_java_gateway
if grep  "is running..." /tmp/status_zabbix_java_gateway
then
    echo "zabbix-java-gateway is runnign on $HOSTNAME"
    echo " "
rm -rf /tmp/status_zabbix_java_gateway
else
echo "zabbix-java-gateway is stopped on $HOSTNAME"
echo " "
output=`ps aux|grep zabbix_java`
set -- $output
pid=$2
kill $pid
sleep 2
kill -9 $pid >/dev/null 2>&1
sleep 2
rm -rf /var/run/zabbix/zabbix_java.pid
echo "zabbix-java-gateway is stopped on $HOSTNAME!!!" > /tmp/mail_zabbix_java_gateway
mail -s "Zabbix Java Gateway is down on !!!" somemail@hotmail.com < /tmp/mail_zabbix_java_gateway
/etc/init.d/zabbix-java-gateway restart
rm -rf /tmp/mail_zabbix_java_gateway
rm -rf /tmp/status_zabbix_java_gateway
fi
```

Please give me some advice.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should probably just use the startup.sh script that comes with Zabbix.
Second, why do you need such a check at all? If the gateway is not running properly, you should resolve the underlying problem.